# iOS Push transition showing image from previus view on back action

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios7

I have 2 screens: 1 TableView with items and one View printing an image of the selected cell from the table. There is an imageView in the second view with 100% height and 100% width.

When I'm in the photo screen and I press the back button, the push transition works good, but a little part from the photo doesn't disapear with the transition. 0,5 seconds later this part disapear completly.

[image]

How can i fix it?

Comment: try to set clip subviews (or clip to bounds) for your image view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In photo screen, on `viewDidLoad` do:
`self.view.clipsToBounds = YES`

That will not allow the subviews to be drawn outside your view bounds.